# How can I write a result as csv?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I am trying to save a result as csv in order to do a db.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

payload = {'ID': '18845', 'PS': '1', 'Submit': 'Submit'}
r = requests.post("http://.com", data=payload)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

for row in soup.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr'):
    ans = row.findAll('td')[1].contents
    print (ans) #delete later
```

and I get this

```
['559']
['364']
['529']
['0']
['461.5']
['460']
['460']
```

How can I save these results in a row, by this way?

```
559;364;529;0;461.5;460;460
```

I know this has been asked thousands times, but I've not been able to do it. Thanks!

Comment: How about `print(row.findAll('td')[1].contents[0] + ";", end="")`? PS: This ain't csv. But it will get you the output you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get those `ans` in a list, and then the code to write on csv is fairly simple. Starting from your code, this is approximately how it should look:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

payload = {'ID': '18845', 'PS': '1', 'Submit': 'Submit'}
r = requests.post("http://.com", data=payload)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

with open('some.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    ll = []
    for row in soup.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr'):
        ans = row.findAll('td')[1].contents
        ll.append(ans)
    csvwriter.writerow(ll)
```

You likely don't need to "build" the "ll" list, sure you can get it from "soup". If you need help with that, maybe provide the content of r.text